# Клик на кнопку del как на селектор и как на переменную

Tags: jquery, переменные, css-selectors

Не совсем понимаю логику работы jqury в данном коде (TODO list)

```
$('.del').click(function () {
                li.remove();                
            });
```

Почему интерпритатор удаляет текущий элемент, и следующие, почему не все li-шки http://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/zr4a2v9e/

Если что, проблема правильного удаления решена, сделав $('.del') переменной, тогда она становится частью текущей var li, а не селектором на странице http://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/01py6wgn/  , просто хочется понять особенность поведения в первом случае jq, чем она руководствуется, не тронув более ранние добавленные элементы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Почему интерпритатор удаляет текущий элемент, и следующие, почему не все li-шки
```

потому что функция добавляется к каждому объекту (в коде `var li`), и при нажатии крестика удаляется именно этот объект. Вы ввели себя в заблуждение из - за того что назвали объект `li`. Т е если бы Вы добавляли каждый `li(js)` в массив, а в конце удалили бы весь массив, то удалились бы все `li-шки (dom)`